# ValueError: You must pass a freq argument as current index has none

Tags: python, time-series, pycaret

I'm using pycaret.time_series alpha module but I have this problem avec launching my experiment. I think this is internal to the module. Can anyone help ?

```
`from pycaret.time_series import *

 exp_name = setup(data = df ,index='ds', target='y', fold = 5, fh = 15)`
```

and i got this :

---

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) c:\Users\elsem\Python\Andre_Coach\ts.ipynb Cell 46' in <cell
> line: 1>()
> ----> 1 exp_name = setup(data = df ,index='ds', target='y', fold = 5, fh = 15)

[image][image]

my df looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the type of your data by using

```
df.dtypes
```

check the type of ds that should be

```
ds        datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: getting this same issue, having datetime column type of  datetime64[ns].

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the `ds` column to datetime manually outside pycaret before feeding to setup. That should hopefully resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set solve this by setting the dataframe's date frequency.

For example, to set business day frequency use:

```
df= df.asfreq('B')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use the pycaret-ts-alpha library anymore as it is old and deprecated. Instead, you can use the pre-release version of pycaret now which has the time series module integrated

```
pip install --pre pycaret
```

To solve the particular problem you have, try setting the frequency as mentioned. Alternately, if you data has missing index values (e.g. the walmart data set has missing values for some store-dept combinations), try adding these indices to the data and imputing them in pycaret.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this is how I could solve it :

```
import pandas as pd
df["ds"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ds"])
df=df.set_index("ds")
df.index = df.index.to_period(freq="d")
```

and setup arguments will alter accordingly by removing `index="ds"` as follows :

```
exp_name = setup(data = df, target='y', fold = 5, fh = 15)
```

this works with **pycaret==3.1.0**